# Why is my VBA For Loop stopping after 30 rows of Running

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

```vb
Sub CountFruit()
    Dim RowNumber As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim U As Long
   
    'J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
  
    U = 2
    RowNumber = 0
    ' Turn off at the start
    'TurnOffFunctionality
            
     For i = 1 To 65                    
         ' Check if cell of column 2 matches column 1
         If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & U).Value Then                 
             'Copy results to new Sheet                
             Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & RowNumber + 1)
                
             RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
             U = U + 1
         End If
     Next i
     ' Print total
     Debug.Print "Cell Content "; CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value); " Row number "; RowNumber + 1; " RowNumber equals "; RowNumber; " I equals"; i; " U equal", U

 'TurnOnFunctionality
End Sub
```

---

I am comparing column A & B and the ones that match get the 3 remaining columns of column to get copied over to a new sheet. there are bad entries in the B so i am using reference of column A to salvage the 3 remaining columns from B

The loops only works for 30 rows , which is exactly the length of 1 page( no idea of this is relevant. But i dont know why its stopping in the middle for nothing.
yet the i in the For Loop is at a higher number
and its testing each cell so i am cycling through all the cells with U variable

, if somebody can maybe point out where i might have erred  would be awsome
[image: Original Data]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, I just copy-pasted your code and at the end of the loop i=66, which is correct. Only thing I can think of is that is data related.

Comment: the code runs but it stops copying rows to sheet2 at 30 rows, when there are 100 rows

Comment: here is the data https://mega.nz/file/OMhyFDRR#mAj_2UKkbrq_G_uxYIio87hswmmg7xJY07-sTEYGaw8

Comment: What do you mean by **The loops only works for 30 rows , which is exactly the length of 1 page**? A printing page? If so,  it shouldn't bother VBA. If not, what do you mean?

Comment: I think that what happens is that U is being incremented only when there is a match, but the loop runs 100 times. Probably you need a nested loop.

Comment: Is there a value in A31 that does not appear in column B ?

Comment: I think you got it, yes U is only running when there is a match , but why stop at 30? there are 100 rows  with a few more matches let me double check the Data. Thank you! Love you guys, HAPPY HOLIDAYS

Comment: So i need to take into account the queries that dont match

Comment: Yes CDP1802
 row 31 has nothing in column B !

Comment: Are you just wanting to check if the row below equals or what? Cause it starts off with i=1 and u=2 but if say on the first row it doesn't match, then the next loop i=2 and u=2. What is it supposed to be? If you want it to be the row below. Just use `i + 1` and get rid of the `u`.

Comment: Hello Simon , there are two column , one is comparing itself to the other

Comment: If you have issues like this, it is often helpful to set a breakpoint and run your code step-by-step. The VBA debugger in Excel is actually quite decent (see e.g. https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
Sub CountFruit()

    Dim J As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim U As Long
    Dim Iend As Long
        
    
    'J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
  
    U = 2

            
             For i = 1 To 100
                    
               For U = 1 To 100
                 ' Check if cell of column 2 matches column 1
                If Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & U).Value Then
    
                ' Print total
                Debug.Print "Cell Content "; CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value); " Row number "; J + 1; " J equals "; J; " I equals"; i; " U equal", U
                
                'Copy results to new Sheet
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
                
                J = J + 1
                Exit For

                End If
                
              Next U
            Next i
    

 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jayvee! your answer helped a lot!